# How to see difference of what View in a ExpandableListView was clicked?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

As the title states, I have a ExpandableListView and the child-elements are made up of a "Favorites"-icon as well as a TextView, when the user clicks the Favorites icon the item gets added to his favorites but if he clickts the TextView he navigates to that item.

Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: set click listeners on both them imageview and the textview?

Comment: Thank you, if you posted it as an answer I would have marked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set click listeners on both the imageview and the textview, then you will know what one was clicked